# Porque seno no me da? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

para comenzar, soy principiante, estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual necesito sacar seno, es algo de trigonometria, y me estoy dando cuenta de que no me da el resultado que deberia, al yo darme cuenta del error trate de ver que era la parte del error, pero no lo encuentro y entonces hice esto=

```
console.log(Math.sin(30))
```

lo cual me da -0.9880316240928618

y me deberia de dar 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciones trigonométricas en `javascript`, como [`Math.sin()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) funcionan en radianes. Si 30 es un ángulo sexagesimal (donde la circunferencia tiene 360°), conviértelo primero a radianes.

Es buena idea leer la documentación de las funciones que usamos, pues qué es lo que esperan en los parámetros generalmente está documentado.  La página enlazada, qué es la documentación oficial dice (el énfasis es mio):

> The Math.sin() method returns a numeric value between -1 and 1, which represents the sine of the angle **given in radians**.

Mi traducción libre de eso sería:

> El método Math.sin () devuelve un valor numérico entre -1 y 1, que representa el seno del ángulo **dado en radianes**.

Si no sabes como realizar la conversión del ángulo, la equivalencia es es:

```
1° = π/180
```

Ejemplo:

```js
console.log(Math.sin(0.52359877559830))
```

[Aquí](https://www.google.com/search?q=convertir+de+sexagesimal+a+radianes) encontrarás más información sobre la conversión.

Comment: Amigo, muchisimas gracias